# Unable to set cookie in page object command

Tags: nightwatch.js

I'm trying to set a cookie in a page object command, but it fails.

Here is the page object command:

`setThingTypeCookie: function() {
      return this.api.setCookie({
        name     : "thingType",
        value    : "I am a thingType ID"
      })
      .pause(1);
    },`

When running the test, I receive the following error:

`Error while running .setCookieString() protocol action: unable to set cookie`

Can someone please point out what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Butch